# Observing blackbody radiation in a cavity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

In observing blackbody radiation, the cavity radiation is modelled as standing waves in 3 mutually perpendicular directions. However, I am unable to understand how we observe the radiation since the standing waves are confined inside the cavity. I mean how do the standing waves come out of the cavity so that they can be observed?

Comment: These are simplified models of reality that make calculations easier. You are correct about an actual measurement. In reality we would have to drill a small hole into the cavity and either measure the radiation coming out of that hole or we would have to insert a sensor that is "small" compared to the wavelengths we are interested in. You can make (or buy) a black body source using a well insulated heated dark coated chamber with a small hole that allows the insertion of a detecting device.

Comment: @FlatterMann acha, understood. But I have a question, since the chamber is dark coated that means the walls are good absorber. In that case how do we get standing waves? I mean wouldn't standing waves be formed when walls are good reflectors?

Comment: Instead of talking about "standing waves" one should talk about "cavity modes" instead. A standing wave implies that two modes of the same frequency are excited with the same amplitude. You are absolutely correct that that is not a requirement of the black body cavity problem. Only the thermodynamic average has to be the same, but there simply are no nodes inside a black body cavity in the way they could be found in a resonator that is being excited with a single mode standing wave.