# Blackbody radiation in cavity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation

While reading about blackbody radiation, I am seeing the textbooks saying that a cavity with metallic walls that are perfectly reflecting, with a small hole, can be approximated as blackbody as any radiation entering into the cavity would suffer multiple reflections from the walls and eventually be absorbed. But since the walls are perfectly reflecting, how is the radiation absorbed by the walls? Also, to observe the blackbody radiation, the cavity is heated and electrons in the walls are set into oscillation, thus they emit em radiations which we observe as blackbody radiation from the cavity. What happens to that "extra" radiation, which is trapped inside the cavity?

Comment: they are not perfectly reflecting. that is just a mistake. there would not be extra radiation after the absorption and emission brings the cavity into thermal equilibrium

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/761821/2451